# pressing Enter on Dropdownlist causing postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

My application(asp.net) has few dropdowns which are dynamically created and all of them were AutoPostBack="false". if I select Item from dropdown and press enter it makes auto postback in the application. I tried to handle this issue OnKeydown event , but No Use.

Could some one help on the same .

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: Why are you pressing `Enter`? It's probably triggering the first submit button on your page.

Comment: enter may trigs first submit button. can u provide your code

Comment: Hi Chandan, I found Issue, Page.Form.DefaultButton is there in one of my user control... Can you suggest me if I have multiple usercontrols loaded and  each one have its own button need to configured as Default button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing submit button triggers the first button(forms default button) on the page.

Set `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` on your Buttons. This disables the `"AutoPostback"` on Enter.This prevents Postbacks on Enter completely.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `AutoPostBack="false"` on a drop down list means it won't post back when you change the *selection*, the first button in an ASP.NET form is usually the default option so by pressing return you are probably invoking your forms `submit` button.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the postback when pressing enter inside a dropdown list it shuld be enough to add

```
<asp:DropDownList ...... onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13)"/>
```

But you will have se same problem if a user presses the enter key inside every control of the page. to disable the enter key on the entire page this is the code

```
<body onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide us with your code ? It would be easier to know which control is causing the postback by looking at your code.
My best guess is that you might have an asp.net button having the property "UseSubmitBehavior" set to true so when you are pressing enter the button is what is causing the postback.
To investigate further you can add this line of code to your Page_Load event to detect which control is causing the postback

```
if(IsPostback){
var controlName = page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
}
```

Please let me know should you need any further clarification. :)

Comment: I found Issue, Page.Form.DefaultButton is there in one of my user control... Can you suggest me if I have multiple usercontrols loaded and  each one have its own button need to configured as Default button

Comment: Hello,
Check if the current usercontrol is the active control (if one of its controls is focused) on focus of each control in the usercontrol set the Page.Form.DefaultButton to UseSubmitBehavior.
I don't really recommend this , I would remove the UseSubmitBehavior from all the controls and wait for the user to submit by mouseclick